# Is the n-torsion of an extension of an abelian variety by a torus, finite and flat?

Tags: reference-request, group-schemes, ag.algebraic-geometry

I am looking for reference or hints how to prove the following result.

> Let $G$ be a commutative $S$-group scheme which is the extension of an abelian scheme $A$ by a torus $T$. Then the n-torsion $G[n]$ is a finite flat $S$-group scheme.

Specifically, I have difficulties in showing that $G[n]$ is finite. For a general semi-abelian scheme we know that it is quasi-finite and flat, but not necessarily finite (see e.g. the book Neron Models, Lemma 7.3/2).

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Is $S$ an arbitrary scheme?

Comment: The statement should be true for an arbitrary scheme but I would be happy with an answer for $S= Spec R$ when $R$ is the ring of integers of a finite $\mathbb{Q}_p$-extension. 

Comment: I have seen a generalization of this statement in several papers on 1-motives, however no proof or reference is given there. For example: Deligne [Hodge III, 10.1.10] or M. Raynaud, [1-Motifs et Monodromie Géométrique, 3.1]. This is why I think that it should be true. 

Comment: @Tzanko Matev: In "Néron models", semi-abelian means flat and semi-abelian fibers, the scheme itself is not necessarily an extension of an abelian scheme by a torus. For example if we consider the Néron model of an elliptic curve with multiplicative reduction, it is semi-abelian in the sense of "Néron models", and the $n$-torsion is not finite in general. 

Comment: @Qing Liu: I am sorry if the question was not stated well. I know that  for a general semi-abelian scheme what I ask is false. I am only interested in the case when the scheme is an extension of an abelian scheme by a torus.

Comment: @Tzanko,  you actually clearly made the difference between semi-ablian schemes and extension of abelian schemas by tori.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is an exercise with descent theory and the snake lemma for fppf abelian group sheaves to deduce the result for $G[n]$ from the cases of $T[n]$ and $A[n]$.

In more detail, by the snake lemma $G[n]$ is an extension of $A[n]$ by $T[n]$ in the sense of such abelian sheaves. Since $A[n]$ and $T[n]$ are each finite fppf over $S$, the same then holds for $G[n]$. Indeed, rather generally, if
$$1 \rightarrow G' \rightarrow G \rightarrow G'' \rightarrow 1$$
is a complex of $S$-group schemes with $G'$ affine fppf over $S$ and the diagram is short exact for the fppf topology (so $G'$ is the scheme-theoretic kernel of $G \rightarrow G''$) then the functor of points of $G$ as a $G''$-scheme is a $G'$-torsor for the fppf topology on $G''$, so the $G''$-scheme $G \rightarrow G''$ becomes isomorphic *fppf-locally on $G''$* to $G'$ (over the base) as a scheme.  Hence, by fppf descent for properties of morphisms, $G \rightarrow G''$ inherits many "nice" properties that may be satisfied by $G' \rightarrow S$, such as: proper, flat, smooth, etale, finite, etc.  In particular, $G$ is fppf over $G''$ and if $G'$ is finite over $S$ then so is $G \rightarrow G''$ (and hence so is $G$ if $G''$ is 
also finite over $S$).

See Oort's LNM book on commutative group schemes for generalizations with the fpqc topology (around section 18, IIRC).